# NotSupportedException Error for getcurrentDirectory()

Tags: c#, file-io, notsupportedexception

I'm using VS 2008 on a Windows 8 laptop and get a `NotSupportedException` when the debugger hits this line of code `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. Could anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

[error image](http://s76.photobucket.com/user/Daemian_Koh/media/Capture_zpsf7afc8b4.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there are only two situation in which you can get this exception.

- The operating system is Windows CE, which does not have current
  directory functionality.
- This method is available in the .NET Compact
  Framework, but is not currently supported.

Windows 8 is not [Windows CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE), so I guess you have installed .NET Compact Framework.

Comment: base on the documentation, I don't understand this part which they mention: This method is available in the .NET Compact Framework, but is not currently supported. Because i believe i have the latest .Net Framework. Does that mean .Net Compact framework unable to run this method?

Comment: Plese check what version you have installed in Windows "Programs and Features". Yes, it means it's available in API but cannot be used.

Comment: I got the list of framework, 

.net compact framework 2.0 SP2
.net compact framework 3.5
.net framework 4.5

Comment: Your project probably targets one of the compact frameworks instead of the latest. Just installing the latest one does not mean it will be used. When you right-click the project and select properties, there's a tab Application an there's Target framework textbox. Check there if you are using the full version.

Comment: I did what you say, but there is nothing on the Target framework textbox. It is empty.

Comment: @user1568459 Sorry, it's combobox, not textbox. There should be option to select from all your installed .NET Framework versions. It can't be empty, you have to target some version.

Comment: anyway thanks for your help, i just found out that it is running on .net compact framework and all this function is not supported any more. Will think of another way to get around with. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location

```
   string startuppath = IO.Path.GetFolderName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location);
```

Comment: System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is just a testing method for me. Cause i plan to open file in it and i trying to check what's wrong with it. Does that mean i cant use the method which is available ?